# Proof that every invertible matrix is a change of base - matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently studying for my upcoming linear algebra exam, and I came accross this statment:

Let $V$ be a vector space over an arbitrary field $F$.

$B = (v_1,....,v_n)$ is a basis for $V$, and $P$ is a $n\times n$ invertible matrix.

Then there exists a basis $C$ for $V$ such that $[\mathit{Id}]_{\text{C}}^{\text{B}} = P$

This seems like a very strong stament, how does one prove such thing, and how could I think about it intuitively?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the columns of $P$, when interpreted as the components of vectors expressed in the basis $B$, constitute a basis.

Comment: Could you please work a proof for me to see? (if you have spare time for it ofcourse)